# Selenium ChromeDriver object in multiple class

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a main class and initiated the chrome driver. I want to use the same driver object in multiple classes. But i m not able to do so. When i run the script it throws NullPointerexception error. Below are my 2 sample classes.

**Class 1:**

```
package seleniumWebCmnd;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DriverConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String exePath = "D:\\Sudhakar DND\\Selenium_Eclipse\\JAR files\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        //Exe1.main(args);
        System.out.println("Into Main function");

        Exe1 Ob2 = new Exe1();
        Ob2.page2();
    }

}
```

So,How to use the Driver object created above in the below class ?

**Class 2**

```
package seleniumWebCmnd;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Exe1 extends DriverConfig {

WebDriver driver;

    public  void page2() {


        String PgTitle=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Into Class 2");
        System.out.println("Page title is :" + PgTitle);

    }

}
```

*Here is the result shown in eclipse console*

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961) on port 20675
Only local connections are allowed.
Into Main function
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at seleniumWebCmnd.Exe1.page2(Exe1.java:30)
    at seleniumWebCmnd.DriverConfig.main(DriverConfig.java:23)
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create another class and write the Chrome browser code in a function and extend this to get the function in any program

```
public class OpenBrowser
{
      public void chromeMethod()
      {
        String exePath = "D:\\Sudhakar DND\\Selenium_Eclipse\\JAR files\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      }
}
```

Now in another class where you want to get the driver,just extend OpenBrowser class and call chromeMethod()

```
public class newMethod extends OpenBrowser
{
  chromeMethod();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  // your statements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the `driver` object inside main
You have to pass the `driver` object to the `Exel` class to access it.

But,you have extended `DriverConfig` so put the code inside constructor of `DriverConfig`. Make the `driver` available to the `Exel` by creating it as a memeber or go for a getter like

```
public class DriverConfig {

    public WebDriver driver;

    public DriverConfig() {
        String exePath = "D:\\Sudhakar DND\\Selenium_Eclipse\\JAR files\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Exe1.main(args);
        System.out.println("Into Main function");

        Exe1 Ob2 = new Exe1();
        Ob2.page2();
    }

}
```

And in Exel class remove the variable declaration

```
class Exe1 extends DriverConfig {

    public void page2() {

        String PgTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Into Class 2");
        System.out.println("Page title is :" + PgTitle);

    }

}
```